# Problema con metodo actualizar en Base de Datos

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo este método **guardar** en una clase que controla los eventos de frame:

```
    if(e.getSource()== estMostrar.getBtnModificar()){

        String nombre= estMostrar.getTxtNombre().getText();
        String materia= estMostrar.getTxtMatricula().getText();
        String nota= estMostrar.getTxtNota().getText();

        this.estDAO.actualizar(new Estudiante(nombre, materia, Integer.parseInt(nota)));
        this.ListarTabla(estAdmin.getTablaEstudiante());

        this.LimpiarCampos();
        this.estMostrar.dispose();
    }
```

El método que introduce los datos para ser guardados es el **estDAO.actualizar**:

```
this.estDAO.actualizar(new Estudiante(nombre, materia, Integer.parseInt(nota)));
```

Este lo que hace es que manda los datos como parámetros al método del DAO que maneja la consulta:

```
    public void actualizar(Estudiante e) {
    Connection con= null;
    PreparedStatement pstm= null;

        try {
            con= dbcon.conectar();

            String sql= "UPDATE notas SET nombre= ?, matricula= ?, nota= ?";
            pstm= con.prepareStatement(sql);

        pstm.setString(1, e.getNombre());
        pstm.setString(2, e.getMatricula());
        pstm.setInt(3, e.getNota());

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al conectar a la BD");
        }finally{
            dbcon.desconectar(con);
        }
}
```

Pero al comprobar la Base de Datos el objeto que he modificado sigue siendo el mismo, podrían decirme si hay algo mal en el código o como puedo solucionar el problema, gracias de antemano.

Por orden del profesor no puedo modificar el método **actualizar**, pues forman parte de una **interfaz** y el no desea que esa interfaz cambie; finalmente opté por modificarlo según sus recomendaciones, he dejado el método **modificar** de esta manera:

```
    if(e.getSource()== estMostrar.getBtnModificar()){

        int fila= estAdmin.getTablaEstudiante().getSelectedRow();

        int id= Integer.parseInt(estAdmin.getTablaEstudiante().getValueAt(fila, 0).toString());

        String nombre= estMostrar.getTxtNombre().getText();
        String materia= estMostrar.getTxtMatricula().getText();
        String nota= estMostrar.getTxtNota().getText();

        this.estDAO.actualizar(new Estudiante(nombre, materia, Integer.parseInt(nota)), id);
        this.ListarTabla(estAdmin.getTablaEstudiante());

        this.LimpiarCampos();
        this.estMostrar.dispose();
    }
```

Sin embargo, ahora el método me da una excepción **NumberFormatException**, intento seleccionar un objeto de un JTable para modificarlo y a la hora de presionar el botón **getBtnModificar** el método da este **stackTrace**:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "fklm"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at comm.estudiante.dao.controlador.ControladorEstudiante.actionPerformed(ControladorEstudiante.java:220)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

la fila 220 es esta:

```
int id= Integer.parseInt(estAdmin.getTablaEstudiante().getValueAt(fila, 0).toString());
```

Comment: Hola!! pon el método actualizar de tu DAO, para saber si es algún problema de consulta

Comment: Ya modifique la pregunta

Comment: Pero porque realizas un INSERT si para actualizar seria un UPDATE

Comment: Actualiza la pagina por favor, ya la modifique

Comment: ¡Cuidado! a ese `update` le falta el `where`!!. Por fortuna, la [respuesta de oscar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/23112/21) cubre esa parte, aunque no lo menciona.

Comment: @jachguate gracias por la observación, ya he modificado mi respuesta y hago referencia al where!!

Comment: Hay alguna forma de hacer el UPDATE sin utilizar mas parámetros a parte del que tiene el método **actualizar**, es para una clase y se nos pidió que no modificáramos los métodos base, solo las consultas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te falta ejecutar la consulta ademas del where, y que tu método al invocarlo recibe dos parámetros, y tu solo tienes uno,intenta con esto

```
public void actualizar(Estudiante e, int id) {
    Connection con= null;
    PreparedStatement pstm= null;

        try {
            con= dbcon.conectar();

            String sql= "UPDATE notas SET nombre= ?, matricula= ?, nota= ? WHERE id = ?";
            pstm= con.prepareStatement(sql);

        pstm.setString(1, e.getNombre());
        pstm.setString(2, e.getMatricula());
        pstm.setInt(3, e.getNota());
        pstm.setInt(4, id);
        //ejecutamos el sql
        pstm.executeUpdate() ;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al conectar a la BD");
        }finally{
            dbcon.desconectar(con);
        }
}
```

Comment: @David, con la forma de manejar la excepción, te estas comiendo toda la  información que esta incluye sobre el error. Agregale al showMessage la información de la excepción, por lo menos el mensaje de error de la misma.

Comment: No me había dado cuenta que le habías pasado el **int** arriba, si bien así podría funcionar pero no se como hacerme para instanciar el método y pasarle un int cuando este ya dentro del método **guardar**, disculpen si pregunto mucho es que no se mucho de programación

Comment: @jachguate o mejor aún, logear el stacktrace en alguna parte para revisar a detalle los problemas. El mensaje a veces es tan simple que no te permite revisar qué es lo que realmente ocasiona un problema.

Answer (score 0):

Para todo el que tiene el problema que copila su programa y no ve la actualizacion es por que al dar clic en la celda y modificarla darle click seguido dentro de la tabla en el cuadro blanco no en otra fila y luego dar en actualizar y listo no es problema del metodo creado si no de la tabla del diseño espero ahorrarles muchas horas de intentos.

Hola ami me funciono esa respuesta la encontre aqui:
https://app.aluracursos.com/forum/topico-solucion-metodo-actualizar-error-212539

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).